# IPython Notebook not launching Firefox

Tags: firefox, jupyter-notebook

I've been using IPython Notebook for my students for 2 years.

But, in the latest (>= 46 ?) versions of Firefox, I have noticed that Firefox would not start any more. (This is under Linux Debian Jessie.)

Instead (if I start IPython Notebook from a terminal), I'm overwhelmed by this error message:

```
[W 17:50:29.933 NotebookApp] ipywidgets package not installed.  Widgets are unavailable.
[I 17:50:29.947 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/daniel
[I 17:50:29.947 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 17:50:29.947 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 17:50:29.947 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
1464018631008   FirefoxAccounts   ERROR   Failed to get data from the login manager: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80570016 (NS_ERROR_XPC_GS_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.getService]"  nsresult: "0x80570016 (NS_ERROR_XPC_GS_RETURNED_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm :: XPCU_serviceLambda :: line 230"  data: no] Stack trace: XPCU_serviceLambda()@resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm:230 < XPCU_defineLazyGetter/<.get()@resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm:198 < LoginManagerStorage.prototype.get<()@resource://gre/modules/FxAccountsStorage.jsm:556 < TaskImpl_run()@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:315 < TaskImpl()@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:276 < createAsyncFunction/asyncFunction()@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:250 < this.FxAccountsStorageManager.prototype._doReadAndUpdateSecure<()@resource://gre/modules/FxAccountsStorage.jsm:319 < TaskImpl_run()@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:315 < TaskImpl()@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:276 < createAsyncFunction/asyncFunction()@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:250 < this.FxAccountsStorageManager.prototype._initialize<()@resource://gre/modules/FxAccountsStorage.jsm:88 < TaskImpl_run()@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:315 < Handler.prototype.process()@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:933 < this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop()@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:812 < this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<()@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:746 < Spinner.prototype.observe()@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.jsm:529
1464018631014   addons.xpi-utils   ERROR   Failed to load XPI JSON data from profile: TypeError: XPIProvider.installLocationsByName is null (resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProviderUtils.js:331:5) JS Stack trace: DBAddonInternal@XPIProviderUtils.js:331:5 < this.XPIDatabase.parseDB@XPIProviderUtils.js:662:24 < this.XPIDatabase.asyncLoadDB/this._dbPromise<@XPIProviderUtils.js:765:9 < Handler.prototype.process@Promise-backend.js:933:23 < this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@Promise-backend.js:812:7 < this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@Promise-backend.js:746:11 < Spinner.prototype.observe@AsyncShutdown.jsm:529:9
1464018631016   addons.xpi-utils   WARN   Rebuilding add-ons database from installed extensions.
1464018631016   addons.xpi-utils   ERROR   Failed to rebuild XPI database from installed extensions: TypeError: XPIProvider.installLocations is null (resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProviderUtils.js:1906:14) JS Stack trace: processFileChanges@XPIProviderUtils.js:1906:14 < this.XPIDatabase.rebuildDatabase@XPIProviderUtils.js:812:9 < this.XPIDatabase.parseDB@XPIProviderUtils.js:683:7 < this.XPIDatabase.asyncLoadDB/this._dbPromise<@XPIProviderUtils.js:765:9 < Handler.prototype.process@Promise-backend.js:933:23 < this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@Promise-backend.js:812:7 < this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@Promise-backend.js:746:11 < Spinner.prototype.observe@AsyncShutdown.jsm:529:9
```

However, if I start Firefox manually afterwards and point it to http://localhost:8888/, I can see the notebooks as expected, and they are fully functional.

I have found no better workaround than switching to Iceweasel as default browser. It lags a few version numbers behind, so for now it doesn't exhibit this problem (nor the above error). But obviously, that's only a temporary solution, so I'm looking for a more permanent fix.

TIA for any advice. Best regards, Daniel

Comment: Jupyter is using the [webbrowser module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) from the Python standard library to launch the browser. Can you try invoking Firefox through that? It sounds like something in Firefox's config is corrupt or something. It's still working for me with Firefox 46.0.1 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thx for reply. Good to know that it still works. I'm convinced that something is messed up in my Firefox config, since I can't invoke it from the command line:
([link=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7134010/firefox_error.txt]link to Firefox error[/link]).
Any hope of recovering without destroying my whole Firefox config? (after all, much of it is found also in Iceweasel, which is now Firefox ESR...)

Comment: I don't know enough about Firefox to really say, I'm afraid. It's bizarre that it fails from the command line but you can still launch it from the menu (I'm guessing that's what you meant about 'I start Firefox manually afterwards'). Perhaps try to find out what the menu entry does and replicate that precisely. The failure looks like it's something to do with a Firefox account, so maybe try signing the browser out of your account.

Comment: More precisely, IPython-Notebook should launch Firefox after its own start. _This_ fails, either from menu or command line. Manually launching Firefox afterwards (either way) does work, though.
Besides, it is true that I sync my main PC with another one. But alas, no luck, if I disconnect from Firefox account, nothing changes.
At present I'm checking the various plugins and add-ons in Firefox.

Comment: If you use the `webbrowser` Python module (part of the standard library) to launch it, does it fail in the same way?

Comment: No, if Firefox is set as default browser, then the typical example (from Python help):
`python -m webbrowser -t "http://www.python.org"`
results in more or less the same error message as in my original post.
(It does work, however, with Iceweasel as default.)

Comment: OK, then the next step is to work out what command `webbrowser` uses to launch FF, and see if you can replicate the error by running that command.

Comment: Well... several things happened today:
1) Iceweasel (AKA Firefox-ESR) was updated to version 45. Would not work anymore. I downgraded it.
2) I learned that IPython notebook was now to be invoked with `jupyter notebook`. Yet, still no luck with Firefox.
3) Firefox (regular) got updated to version 47... which resumed working (though the command line produces a load of complaints).
So, problem solved--but not understood.